# Okay so, I am having trouble connecting to my server from the outside. I disabled firewall, I opened the correct ports, but I still can't get in

Tags: networking, server, firewall, minecraft

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460. I am trying to run a minecraft server, so I have the port 25565 open, and it works fine when I join from the local network, but when I use my mobile hotspot to try to connect (to simulate a friend joining) it just says that the server timed out. This also happens when I try to ping the server from command prompt, it just says it timed out. My ISP is comcast if that helps, I think they might just be blocking it because I don't see anything I'm doing wrong. I disabled UFW, all the right ports are open. (by having all the ports open, I meant on my router)

Comment: How are you pinging it? Do you have a public IP set on the server? Or is the public IP on your router?

Comment: if the laptop is behind a router you need to port forward on the router to make it work.  that's not an ubuntu issue though, that's just needing to do port forwarding properly on the router

Comment: Did you configure port forwarding on your router? Is your external IP address a routable address? If you are unsure show your external IP address as shown in your router. (Don't use services like "whatismyip" because this might show a wrong address if your ISP uses carrier grade NAT.)

Comment: I did the port forwarding on my router. and what is a "routable address"?

Comment: If you are still having problems, it's likely because you did not answer @Dan's questions, which are about the most common mistakes folks make. A "routable address" means an IP address that is NOT in the 192.168.*.* nor 10.*.*.* ranges. Those addresses are un-routable (LAN-only). Whatever tutorial you followed should have told you that.

Comment: I did not follow a tutorial, I did this just of my own knowledge, and apparently that failed me. Thank you.